# Scale outlier data to normalized data for visualization in R

Tags: r, statistics, normalization, outliers

I'm working with some data that has a few major outliers, mostly due to the technology used to capture the data. I removed these to normalize the data; however, for the nature of the work, I've been asked to visualize every participant's results in a series of graphs in order to compare performances. I'm a little new to R, so while the normalization wasn't difficult, I'm a little stumped as to how I might go about re-introducing these outliers to the scale of the normalized data. Is there a way to scale outliers to previously normalized data (mean=0) without skewing the data?

EDIT: I realize I left a lot of info out (still new to asking questions here), so here's an example of what my process looks like right now:

```
#example data of 20 participants, 18 of which are normal-range and 2 of which 
#are outliers in a data frame
time <- rnorm (18, mean = 30, sd = 10)
distance <- rnorm(18, mean = 100, sd = 20)
time <- c(time, 2, 100)
distance <- c(distance, 30, 1000)
df <- data.frame(time, distance)
```

The outliers were mostly known due to the nature of the data collection, so removed them:

```
dfClean <- df[-c(19, 20),]
```

And plotted the data to check for normalcy after (step skipped here because data was generated to be normal). 
From there, I normalized the columns in the data set so that each variable would have a mean of 0 and a st of 1 so they could be plotted together. The goal is to use this as a "normal" range to be able to visualize spread and outliers in future data (accent on visualization).

```
#using package clusterSim
dfNorm <- data.Normalization(dfClean, type="n13", normalization = "column")
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to scale outliers to this range afterwards...or if I'm even understanding the scale function correctly. So, how do I plot all the subjects in the original df, including outliers, on a normalized mean=0 scale?

Comment: That sounds like more statistical question than programing

Comment: It would be helpful to see just what you did to normalize your data. You say mean=0, but did you also make sd=1?  Did you use the `scale` function or did you make the adjustments yourself?

Comment: You're right...I definitely need to add more information. I'll edit the post. There's a lot in this process I'm unclear about, and unfortunately I'm left a little to my own devices with figuring it out :x

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if we can provide any external links to solve stackoverflow's issue.
Still you can refer below links to relove your problem-

```
 https://www.r-bloggers.com/identify-describe-plot-and-remove-the-outliers-from-the-dataset/
```

I used this many times and found it useful.